# check if wifi is connected every 5 minutes after screen is off

Tags: android

I have found good tutorial to for Handling Screen OFF and Screen ON Intents: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

but i want that after screen is off every 5 minutes wifi is checked if is connected

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
wifi.isConnected()
```

i want to use `alarm manager` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html but i don't know how to check every 5 minutes if is connected or not.

Comment: use pending intent to wake up the alarm after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first declare a Timer like the following:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
```

then assing arguments to the timer as below:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new checkWifi, 0,50000);
```

then define the checkWifi task as below:

```
class checkWifi extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        //here put the code that will check if the wifi is connected or not
       ConnectivityManager connManager =         (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
         wifi.isConnected()
     }
   };
```

Comment: thank you. Where can i use Timer. In broadcast receiver or in service?

Comment: either one would be fine with it just make sure that you place timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new checkWifi, 0,50000); in place of your interest

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is totally crappy, timer is redundant.
Just create broadcast receiver for [WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION).

Comment: thank ou but this has nothing to do with time. This will not help me to check for it ever 5 minutes...

Comment: yes but checking every 5 minutes has no sense when you can get notification when state of WiFi is changing. You should describe your use-case to explain why relay timer is needed (apparently you needed for a different reason).